# Swift SpriteKit Label not being removed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I have 2 labels that are added when the player loses; however, when restarting the game, 1 label remains. I don't see any code where the label could be duplicated by accident.

Adding the labels:

```
func getScores(x: SKScene) {

    //HighScore
    if currentScore > highScore
    {
        Defaults.setInteger(currentScore, forKey: "High Score")
        //High Score Particles
        //highScoreParticle()
    }

    //High Score
    highScoreLabel      = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x.frame.midX - 100 , y: x.frame.midY + 70, width: 200, height: 50))
    highScoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    highScoreLabel.text = "HighScore: \(Defaults.valueForKey("High Score")!)"
    highScoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue UltraLight", size: 30)
    highScoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    x.view?.addSubview(highScoreLabel)

    //Current Score
    currentScoreLabel      = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x.frame.midX - 50 , y:  x.frame.midY, width: 100, height: 50))
    currentScoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    currentScoreLabel.text = "Score: \(currentScore)"
    currentScoreLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue UltraLight", size: 30)
    currentScoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    x.view?.addSubview(currentScoreLabel)
}
```

Removing the labels:

```
func resetGame(scene: SKScene) {

    //Removes Labels
    startLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    currentScoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    highScoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()

    //Remove everything off scene
    scene.removeAllChildren()
    scene.removeAllActions()

    //Reset Variables
    currentScore = 0
}
```

`highScoreLabel` does not get removed from the scene

Comment: Stackoverflow is _not_ a forum. Do not edit your question's title to add stuff like the tags or [solved]. Also do not edit your question to insert your solution. That what _answers_ are for. See the [faq].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a UILabel to the scenes view controller.  the scene doesnt have control over that.  you need to create an SKLabelNode instead and add it to the scene using `addChild`

Comment: Even though all works well now, why does the current score label get removed correctly if i am doing the exact same thing?

Comment: really couldnt tell you :)